# WSO2 EI - Cannot set SOAP header with OAuth Token

Tags: oauth, bearer-token, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have configured a WSDL Proxy Service on WSO2 EI which points to an external service secured by OAuth.

My problem is that, beside all my efforts, i cannot set the Bearer Authorization header on my service calls. The service endpoint always returns "Cannot find oauth token" error. I've already tried all WSO2 tutorials and documentations about headers (using Header Mediator and header as a property) but nothing works.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485069/does-wso2-esb-4-5-0-oauth-mediator-support-oauth2-0-bearer-token), also without anwser.

The WSDL Proxy service is consumed by a WCF .NET Application and the Bearer header is been set.

This is the XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="WSDLProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <wsdl port="RegisterEndpoint"
                        service="RegisterService.serviceagent"
                        uri="[external-wsdl-uri]"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="[external-wsdl-uri]"/>    
</proxy>
```

Comment: Did you solve that?

How to use Bearer token on header to call service?

Answer (score 0):

In a passthrough scenario, such as the given sample of the WSDL proxy service, 'Authorization' header will be sent to the backend service if it is sent in the client's request for 'WSDLProxy'. However, if your client sends the Bearer token in a custom transport header, you will have to set it as the 'Authorization' header prior to the backend call, as follows.

```html
...
 <inSequence>
    <property expression="get-property('transport', 'CUSTOM-Bearer')" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <property action="remove" name="CUSTOM-Bearer" scope="transport"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <wsdl port="RegisterEndpoint"
                service="RegisterService.serviceagent"
                uri="[external-wsdl-uri]"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
 </inSequence>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but still not working. The authorization header is been sent to proxy service (i've turned on wire debug) but the not to the endpoint. One thing i didn't mentioned before is that "externa-wsdl-uri' points to a local WSDL file which contains the external endpoint address (doing this because of some network restrictions).